# How make Angular website call API that is behind firewall?

Tags: angular, api, firewall

can the public-facing angular website call an api that resides behind the firewall? Or that API should also be public facing?
Suggestions? work arounds? We do need to keep API on internal network, not exposed to public. Windows environment.

Comment: Unless it's publicly exposed, it's impossible to reach.

Answer (score 2):

The internal API may be made available to the outside world if the firewall supports NAT. This way you can route all requests that arrives at the gateway on a specific port to another port on a machine connected to the internal network.

This may be a static mapping, or created by another protocol such as uPnP.

The way to register a NAT depends heavily on what platform is available on the server side. [This library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Open.Nat/) works for C# implementations.